# How do I get all IP addresses assigned to the machine?

Tags: go, ip-address, network-interface

Given the following code:

```
// iptest
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    host, _ := os.Hostname()
    addrs, _ := net.LookupIP(host)
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        if ipv4 := addr.To4(); ipv4 != nil {
            fmt.Println("IPv4: ", ipv4)
        }   
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem where it only returns the first IP address assigned to the adapter.  This appears to be a problem only on systems that have a DNS suffix defined.  If one is not defined, it works fine and reports all IPs that have been assigned.

Comment: `LookupIP` can only look up the IP address via the resolver with the given hostname. It knows nothing about what IPs are bound to what interfaces.

Comment: Thanks @JimB. Any idea why it would work fine on a system that doesn't have a DNS suffix defined?

Comment: If it doesn't have a DNS name, that probably means it's listed in /etc/hosts, or looked up via another mechanism via /etc/nsswitch.conf. If you want all local IP addresses, then you have to enumerate them yourself.

Comment: @JimB But that doesn't seem to explain why I don't have to enumerate them myself when I use the exact same code on another system. The only difference on that system is that a DNS suffix is not defined.  Also, a hostname is defined on the system that it is not working and I have confirmed that Go is detecting it properly through fmt.Println(hostname)

Comment: `LookupIP` is returning what the local resolver responds with. I don't know exactly what you mean by "DNS suffix", but check how the names you're looking up are resolved on a system level first (i.e. is it resolving from /etc/hosts or another nsswitch source). You can also run `GODEBUG=netdns=1` to see if there is any useful info about what resolver decisions the go net package makes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to get the addresses currently assigned to the machine.  I think you should consider using `net.InterfaceAddrs()` instead of trying to do a DNS lookup for the hostname.  Here's a short example that will give you all the IPs on the local machine.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    addrs, _ := net.InterfaceAddrs()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", addrs)
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        fmt.Println("IPv4: ", addr)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if you're curious to learn more about Go DNS resolution you can visit here: https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: N.B. Running this on Go version 1.17.3 (and likely earlier versions) also shows IPv6 addresses (on windows 10).